# Django update_or_create is updating even if there is no change?

Tags: django

I have a user with the name field "jule".
If i try to update it with exactly the same name like this :

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(first_name='jule', defaults={'first_name': 'jule'})
```

Will this make an action in my database? Or does the django ORM detect that there is no change to make (and not do any action in my database then) ?

I need this to optimize my code wihtin a loop :)

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

> The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields passed in the defaults dictionary.
>
> This is meant as a shortcut to boilerplatish code. For example:
>
> ```
> defaults = {'first_name': 'Bob'}
> try:
>     obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
>     for key, value in defaults.items():
>         setattr(obj, key, value)
>     obj.save()
> except Person.DoesNotExist:
>     new_values = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Lennon'}
>     new_values.update(defaults)
>     obj = Person(**new_values)
>     obj.save()
> ```

the sample code describes what exactly the `update_or_create` does.

Comment: Thank you, but if i change the name by the same name. Django ORM will update the name with same name in database ? Or django ORM will see it's same name and that does not need to be update ?

Comment: @ValentinGarreau It will update the field (hit the database), whether it changed or not.

Comment: But how to see the changes? if any

Answer (score 1):

No, you've just used `first_name='jule'` as a filter to get the db entry. That only will check and will not do any update since you are not using `defaults` dict in the call.

More info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Some more info about the case when it is created.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/d6505273cd889886caca57884fa79941b18c2ea6/django/db/models/query.py#L576

It doesn't do any update if the object didn't exist. Just creates it.
You don't have to put `defaults={'first_name': 'jule'}` into the method since it is done by Django "under the hood".

defaults dict is a dict with extra changes, using `defaults` you can "rename" your user I believe by passing a new name, but don't need to pass the same params there :)